# Conditional expectation with mismatched densities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose, we have r.v. $X,Y,Z$. Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent.
Suppose all of the variables have zero mean and finite second moment.

Next, suppose that $E_Y[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y])^2]< \infty$ and is defined as
\begin{align*}
E_Y[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y])^2] = \int  (E_{X|Y}[X|Y=y])^2 f_Y(y) dy 
\end{align*}
What can we say about conditional expectation $E_Z[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=Z])^2]$ defined as
\begin{align*}
E_Z[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=Z])^2]=\int (E_{X|Y}[X|Y=z])^2f_Z(z) dz
\end{align*}
Is it zero since $X$ and $Z$ are independent? Or is it just $(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=z])^2$ averaged over a wrong distribution?

Using Jensen's inequality and law of total expectation one can show that 
\begin{align*}
E_Z[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=Z])^2] \le E_Z[E_{X|Y}[X^2|Y=Z]] = E[X^2]< \infty
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can we say about conditional expectation $E_Z[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=Z])^2]$ defined as
>   $$E_Z[(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=Z])^2]=\int(E_{X|Y}[X|Y=z])^2f_Z(z)\mathrm dz$$

That it should be:

$$E_Z[(E_{X\mid Y=Z}[X|Y=Z])^2]=\int(E_{X|Y,Z}[X|Y=z,Z=z])^2f_Z(z)\mathrm dz$$

We're told that $X$ is independent of $Z$, but we *don't* know if $X$ is conditionally independent of $Z$ when given $Y$.

Comment: Thank you. For the suggestion. Maybe my notation is not the best but. Nontheless I am interested in the quantity $\int (E_{X|Y}[X|Y=z])^2 f_Z(z) dz$

Comment: Well, that is $\displaystyle\int \left(\int x f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid z) \operatorname d x\right)^2 f_Z(z) \operatorname d z$ and ... we can't say much more about it since we don't know if $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks. This just using a wrong distribution for $Y$ right? It has nothing to do with independence of $X$ and $Z$ right?

Comment: That's right.  @Boby